# Delegates, Event Handler and Controls.OfType

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

i have 2 questions about this code.
**1st:**
What is the difference between **1st** way and **2nd** way in the code? i mean there syntax not what they do. which one is prefered?
**2nd:**
in **Controls.OfType** how can we get multiple result for example for **TextBox** and **Button**,here i have written only for TextBox.(Windows form)

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        item.MouseEnter += item_MouseEnter; // 1st way 
        item.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(item_MouseLeave); //2nd way
    }
}
void item_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderButton = (Control)sender;
    senderButton.Height -= 5;
    senderButton.Width -= 5;
}

void item_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderButton = (Control)sender;
    senderButton.Height += 5;
    senderButton.Width += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** There's no difference. The first line will implicitly use EventHandler. This is prefered.

**2nd:** OfType takes only 1 type argument, so it will return only objects of that Type. But you can do the filtering yourself. `Controls.Where(ctrl => ctrl is TextBox || ctrl is Button)`
(This is what OfType does internally anyway.)

Edit: It appears that ControlCollection implements the non-generic IEnumerable, so it does not have an extension method called Where.
So you have to use:

`Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(ctrl => ctrl is TextBox || ctrl is Button)`

(OfType will convert `IEnumerable to IEnumerable<Control>`)

Or you could use a simple if statement inside the loop.

Comment: i can't write it, it gets me error, it doesn't recognize Where, would you mind writing the code?

Comment: another error for OfType<Control>,is not valid in the given context,write it in a foreach loop please,tnx in advance.

Comment: I missed the parentheses, was that the problem? It should be OfType<Control>()